# Dell inspiron LCD image failure

Tags: hardware-failure, dell-inspiron, lcd

Hi i have problem with:

> Dell Model: **INSPIRON 17R**
>
> Model No: **7010-3662**

Problem is that my LCD monitor is showing green color instead of black. I tried to use external monitor connected across HDMI connector and that was working well. Image was without any visible errors. I have changed LCD and LCD cable and still is not working. I tried to push the Start button and keyboard D for LCD settings but without success.

[image: Booting process]
[image: Image in windows]

Comment: Did you change the inverter when replacing the cable?

Comment: No i didn't ...

Comment: I changed whole lcd panel before on which was new inverter so i just replace the cable.

Comment: So the inverter has also been replaced, along with the LCD panel and all connecting cables, correct? Looking to see if all hardware after motherboard has been replaced.

Comment: Yes correct. I replaced all so i am confused why is still problem same. Can it by failure on motherboard or graphic chip ? When it works on external monitor well?